# Convert JPG,GIF,EPS and PDF to PDF with Imagemagick in PHP

Tags: imagemagick

I need to convert jpg,gif and eps files to pdf and vice versa. Is ImageMagick will be the best tool for this ? I have configure imagemagic with ubuntu 11.04 and using CLI trying to convert images into pdf, but quality is too bad. So what whoud be best approch to convertion ?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to support two types of files; [raster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_image) (jpg/gif) and [vectorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) (eps).  Conversion from one set to the other is never lossless.

When converting from vectorial to raster or vice-versa, one crucial parameter is -density, that sets the image size before it gets converted.

Imagemagick is probably the right tool for vectorial to raster, it's just a matter of getting the parameters right.  To transform raster to vectorial, better tools would probably be [autotrace](http://autotrace.sourceforge.net/) or [potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/), but be aware these tools cannot do a perfect conversion.